# R - Non-linear optimization algorithm - linear objective function with binary variables

Tags: r, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have an optimization problem with the following characteristics :

1. Linear objective function with binary variables (only)
2. Non-linear constraints.

I am looking for an adapted algorithm in R. Any ideas?

When I have the same optimization problem but with linear constraints, I use the `ROI::` suite with the Multiple Solution Binary Linear Problem plugin: `ROI.plugin.msbinlp`. I am checking out the `Rsolnp` package but I am yet unable to constraint the solution to integer/binary variables.

Any idea would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Note that non-linear constraints can often be made piecewise linear using binary variables.  Perhaps something to consider.

Comment: Could you provide the function you want to optimize? That would be helpful to provide a solution.